# How to add Sleep in Node.js after executing command?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically this is a chat bot for Twitch.tv. Currently, it replies to someone in the chat when they say "Hello". I'd like to add a Sleep for 2 seconds after the bot replies with hello, so it doesn't flood the chat. I have tried setTimeout/setInterval but those put the 2 second delay BEFORE it replies to the person. Cheers.

```
var tmi = require('tmi.js');

process.setMaxListeners(0);

var options = {
options: {
    debug: true
},
connection: {
    cluster: "aws",
    reconnect: true
},
identity: {
    username: "",
    password: ""
},
channels: [""]
};

var client = new tmi.client(options);
client.connect();

client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
if(message === "Hello") {
    client.action("", "@" + user['display-name'] + ", Welcome!");
}});
```

Comment: Please show us *how* you tried to use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var canSendMessage = true;
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
if(message === "Hello" && canSendMessage ) {
canSendMessage = false;
client.action("", "@" + user['display-name'] + ", Welcome!");
setTimeout(function(){ canSendMessage = true }, 2000);
}});
```

You can try this (Not tested). The variable canSendMessage will block the bot from writing if it is not reseted after 2000ms (2s).